# What does it mean for classical mechanics to be based on the category of sets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, category-theory

It is quite common[[1]](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/quantum/node4.html)[[2]](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/topos_physics/) in the study of physics in the context of category theory to say that one of the fundamental difference between classical mechanics and quantum mechanics is that classical mechanics is based on the category of sets, $\mathbf{Set}$, while quantum mechanics is not. However, what this means exactly isn't quite clear to me.

My first thought was that classical mechanics is based on concrete categories, such as the category of Poisson manifolds or other such categories. However as far as I can tell, this seems to also be true of the category of Hilbert spaces with linear maps, $\mathbf{Hilb}$. An additional issue here is that I am never entirely sure which category is meant here exactly, as a lot of different categories are touted as the category of quantum mechanics, such as Hilbert spaces with linear maps, Hilbert spaces with linear contractions, the spectral presheaf on the commutative subalgebras of the operators on the Hilbert space, etc.

There are quite a lot of ways that such categories can differ from the category of sets, such as the subobject classifier or the internal logic being different, but is there a specific way that the statement that classical systems are based on sets is meant to be understood?

Comment: But the first reference explains this by the example of joint systems, no? I.e. by explaining the difference between tensor products and direct products.

Comment: Is that the fundamental claim, though? I have also read the claim that in fact, Poisson manifolds do have a tensor product that is nigh identical to the Cartesian product (at least on the level of the category of manifolds), the difference there being that there is some bijection between the Cartesian product and the tensor product, or similarly, that the tensor product for them has projection operators.

Comment: I am far from being an expert in Category theory. But physically, one of the distinctions between classical and quantum physics is indeed the "formation" of joint systems.

Comment: That's weird, I think of classical mechanics as involving the category of symplectic manifolds and finite-dimensional QM as involving the category of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces? If category theory is familiar to you, I recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6917